# Matlab sums and integers

Tags: matlab

Thank you for any help in advance. I have a large matrix: 1,000,000 rows and 10 columns. I would like to sum each row and create a new matrix with only the rows that sum to integers. I've tried this so far and manipulated it in many ways, but I'm stuck. How can I do this?

```
for k = 1:1000000
  x = sum(A(k,:)) %A is my large matrix
  if x-round(x,0)==0
    y = [y;x]% y is my new matrix
  end
end
```

Comment: It works for me with a simple test matrix.  What happens if you change the `if`-condition to `if abs(x-round(x,0)) < eps`?

Comment: Can you give more details of the error thrown?

Comment: @TroyHaskin the code above works great for making a matrix of only the sums! however, what I would like is a matrix of rows with all of the elements for each row but only the rows that sum to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `for` loop and continuously expanding `y` which is going to be extremely slow for large `x` arrays, you can use the second input of `sum` to compute the sum for each row, and then you can determine which rows sum to an integer by comparing the rounded and original versions using a very small epsilon (the proper way to compare floating-point numbers).

```
% Sum each row and divide by 3
row_sums = sum(x, 2) / 3;

% Determine which of the row-wise sums are integers
sum_is_integer = abs(round(row_sums) - row_sums) < eps;

% If you want the sums that were integers
y = row_sums(sum_is_integer);

% If you want a sub-matrix containing only the rows where the sums were an integer
z = x(sum_is_integer, :);
```

Comment: Hi @Suever the code above is returning all rows from the original matrix.

Comment: @Michael Are you sure that all the rows don't sum to be integers? Can you provide an example of `x`?

Comment: yes they do not all sum to integers. Maybe a 3rd are integers. The matrix is a permutation of 25 integers with a subset of 9 elements per row.

Comment: If everything is a permutation of integers, the sum of any integers is *also* an integer. Please provide an example matrix in your original question.

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry, the sum of each column is divided by 3. yikes! that's kind of crucial... Then I only want the rows that are integers.